# Ruling of a quadric cone in $A_k^3$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, let $A=k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, and let $X= \operatorname{Spec} A$. Then $X$ is an affine quadric cone in $A_k^3$. We want to show that $Cl(X)=\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and that it is generated by a ruling of the cone, say $Y: y=z=0$.

I think this is saying that $Y = V(y,z)$, where $V(y,z)$ is the set of all prime ideals of $A$ containing $(y,z)$.

Hartshorne then states that $Y$ can be cut out set theoretically by the function $y$. I am slightly confused by this, $Y$ in my mind would be the $x$-axis (i.e, the set of points at which y=z=0).

Why can this be cut out set-theoretically by the function $y$?

The book then goes onto to claim that the divisor of the function $y$ is $2 \cdot Y$ because $y=0$ implies $z^2-0$, and $z$ generated the maximal ideal of the local ring at the generic point of $Y$.

I really don't understand this last claim. However, I think this is because I don't know how to answer my first question.

Comment: Any prime ideal of $A$ that contains $y$ must also contain $z$, because of the relation.

Comment: On $X$ the equation $x y - z^2=0$ is fulfilled. If you demand $y=0$, then $z^2 = 0$, that is $z = 0$. So $Y=V(y,z)$ is equal to $V(y)$ as a set of closed points. That $y=0$ implies $z^2 = 0$ and not $z=0$ shows, that $y=0$, a principal divisor of $X$ corresponds to $2 Y$ in $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$